# Change integrity level of System32 folder in Vista

Tags: windows, security, windows-7, windows-vista

I have been unsuccessful getting a Java WebStart application that should have AllPermissions to write a file to Windows/System32 on Vista or Windows 7.  While I don't believe this is possible, perhaps there is a way to lower the integrity level of this folder to Medium?

I am getting desperate and am not above insane registry hacks to make this happen.  We have a production app that runs fine on Windows XP however a new prospective client is unbending in their determination to ONLY maintain Windows 7 or Vista workstations.

I appreciate any help or suggestions and would especially love to hear from anybody if this is impossible.  Please no comments on how insecure and dangerous this can be, I am aware of the risks.

Comment: Why does your application *need* to write to System32?  Is there a way to change your application to write to another directory?  That would alleviate the need to be an administrator on both Windows 7 *AND* XP.

Comment: The need drives from the Java SDK of a third party peripheral device that will go unnamed. This SDK of course consists of several DLL and native device drivers that apparently need to be in this folder.  I thought that perhaps it is just because these need to be on the PATH environment variable, but there is still something wrong.  Further this device serves an extremely specific purpose and basically is the only device of its kind with an accompanying Java SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper solution is to have the required DLLs placed in the system32 folder from your installer.

Your MSI installer will know how to prompt the user to elevate to administrator, so you then have permission to add your files to the users System32 folder.

You will not be able to modify files in the users's System32 without them being (or elevating to) an administrator; that's a fundamental constraint of the secure operating system.

Comment: This is a good point, however the application is not installed from an MSI but from Java WebStart.  The advantages of this are that when I update the version of the software on the webserver, every workstation will download this to the WebStart cache and run this the next time.  I know there are services out there that can do this with MSI installers as well however last I checked they are proprietary and pricey.

Comment: If you want your application to be able to be installed without elevation, you'll need to install it someplace else. You should follow what Google Chrome does, and install in `C:\Users\MapleShaft\AppData\Local\SuperCoolJavaApp\CoolBeans.exe`. This is the place where you are supposed to store per-user, non-roaming, application data.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as the author of CHML -- the app you mentioned -- it's unfortunately not a great idea to lower the integrity of the Windows folder (as you've seen).

That said, there IS a way to get things back the way you want -- several, actually, but the easiest way is to

1) Create a bootable WinPE CD or USB stick
2) add my chml.exe executable
3) Boot your system

And at that point you could use chml to re-raise the integrity level.  It works because under WinPE you ARE running as System, and can raise your IL.  (The docs (ahem) DO mention this. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do this for Vista but am really unnerved by what I have done.

There is a free program out there that you can download that will give you the ability to change the integrity level of a folder.  http://www.minasi.com/apps/

Using this program however from the commandline will give you Access Denied when attempting to change System32 to Medium integrity.  This is because the Administrator does not have explicit rights to this directory.

This is where it gets really scary, to give yourself Full Control on System32 you have to make Administrator the Owner of that directory.  The current owner is TrustedInstaller originally.

So, I changed the Owner of System32 to Administrator, Gave Administrator FullControl, then used chml from an Adminstrator command prompt to give System32 Medium integrity.

I now wonder what the consequences could be of System32 having a different Owner, however if Vista allows you to do this out of the box then it can't be that bad.  Right???

Comment: Well, setting System32 to medium integrity didn't fix my problem.  The problem is elsewhere obviously, BUT that is a different question altogether and for all intents and purposes this specific question is answered.

Comment: Changing the ACLs on System32 is one of the easiest ways to break Windows (as in make Windows stop working).  You also open your customers machines up to ANY malware on the internet that wants to write to System32.

Comment: Btw, KB article 885409 has some guidance here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/885409.  Read the "file system and registry access control list modifications" section.

Comment: Thanks for the info!  I agree now that this is a BAD THING and that I feel dirty for even considering it.

Comment: Now I have a significant problem in that after setting the integrity level of System32 to Medium, I am NOW unable to set it back to System!  I get Access Denied despite the fact that I am the owner and have full rights on that directory now.  Great.  I completely fubarred my machine out of my disgusting curiousity.  Do you have any suggestions to fix it before I reimage my PC?

Comment: UPDATE: I repaired my Vista installation by doing a system restore to the previous days checkpoint.  Thank you for talking me out of a bad idea guys!